# Set a non-string variable in a function in a class to get in other PHP files class

Tags: php, class, oop

***Firstly:***

On main.php I can use `$this->tester1` to share the variable between functions, therefore do I need the public $tester1; at the top of my file - it seems to work fine without it?

***Secondly:***

I am attempting to get the variable set in **main.php** on **other.php**, if I remove `$this->tester1 = 'test';` from the function and set `public $tester1 to = 'test';` then `echo $this->tester1;` on either file will output fine.

However instead of 'test' I need the variable to be `= get_option( 'my_option' );` which needs to be called after the `__construct` on the `init` action, and therefore needs to be within the function `mymainfunction`.

If I try to set the variable in that function and try to access it via other.php it says **unexpected PUBLIC**, if I remove public from the variable then the output is **Undefined property: MyMainClass::$tester1**

The output of the `get_option` is a line of text.

I think I am nearly there with this but missing something simple - hopefully! :)

Here are my files:

**main.php**

```
class MyMainClass {

    public $tester1;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'mymainfunction' ) );
    }

    public function mymainfunction() {
        $this->tester1 = 'test';
        echo $this->tester1;
    }

}
```

**other.php**

```
class MyOtherClass {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'myotherfunction' ) );
    }

    public function myotherfunction() {
        require_once 'main.php';
        $getvariables = new MyMainClass();
        echo 'tester1 is:' . $getvariables->tester1;
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

***Firstly:***

If I'm not wrong, declaration without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.

***Secondly:***

You are including a class in the middle of a method of another one.. Seems quite strange to me.. "require_once" just insert the content of a file, where the instruction is called. So my guess is that it's mess up with PHP syntax. In order to try to help you, would you try to replace your "**other.php**" by something like :

```
require_once 'main.php';
class MyOtherClass {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'myotherfunction' ) );
    }

    public function myotherfunction() {
        $getvariables = new MyMainClass();
        echo 'tester1 is:' . $getvariables->tester1;
    }
}
```

But to be honest, I don't know what you are trying to do, but something like this would be simplier, right ?

**main.php**

```
class MyMainClass {
    public $tester1;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tester1 = 'test1';
    }
}
```

**other.php**

```
require_once 'main.php';
class MyOtherClass {
    public function __construct() {
        $main = new MyMainClass();
        echo 'tester1 is:' . $main->tester1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work for a string, but I want to store the get_option as in the question which I can't do inside the __construct, only on the function it calls on init.